# menu layout altering, vertical instead of horizontal on initial load

Tags: css, asp.net, menu, pageload

I have been struggling with this problem for some time now mostly because, it only happens every now and then and I also do not know where to begin on narrowing down the cause of this problem. So occasionally, when my website page loads, the menu bar, which should be horizontal, will load vertically and aligned all the way to the right side of the header.

As I said before this only happens every now and then sometimes it loads just fine, and the menu layout usually corrects itself (horizontally) after refreshing or reloading the page once

here is the css code for the menu

```
div.hideSkiplink
{
margin:0px auto 0px 195px; 
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
right:0;


}


div.menu
{
background-color:#080808;


padding: 0px auto 4px auto; 
}

div.menu ul
{
background-color:#080808;
list-style:none;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
width: auto;
}

div.menu ul li a, div.menu ul li a:visited
{
background-color: #080808;
/* border: 1px #585B5E solid; */
border-right:1px solid #585B5E;
color: #dde4ec;
display: block;
line-height: 2.15em;

padding: 4px 20px;
text-decoration: none;
white-space: nowrap;
}

div.menu ul li a:hover
{
background-color: #bfcbd6;
color: #465c71;
text-decoration: none;
}

div.menu ul li a:active
{
background-color: #465c71;
color: #cfdbe6;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

and below are pictures of what is happening vs. what it should look like.

Incorrect...

[image: Incorrect Layout]

Correct...
[image: Correct]

Any Tips on how to figure out why this is happening are greatly appreciated.

I still haven't been able to figure this out, anyone have any thoughts?
I don't know if it would be some script thats loading before this that is haulting the menu loading or what. Any suggestions on how to figure out why it is doing this would be helpful.

Comment: Please provide full code that reproduces the issue. A Stack snippet or JS Fiddle would be helpful.

Comment: I am kind of a beginner and I am not exactly sure how to capture the full code that reproduces this error? Can I do this by opening up developer tools in the browser and copying the code from that?

Comment: As you appear to be using ASP.NET then yes, you may need to copy the resultant HTML from the browsers "View source" functionality. Once you've got it, trim it down to the minimal amount of code that reproduces the issue. This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you il have display: block property, may be from some parent element.
try to fix it like this:

```
div.menu > ul li{
 float: left !important;
}
```

if this help this mean you have simple problem this display: block propery.

Comment: Do you mean to just delete the `display: block` or are you suggesting that I also need to add `float: left !important`?

Comment: remove display block from li, display block mean that it takes all line width, and the next li will be displayed under it, and not side by side.

Comment: add add the float: left !important;

Comment: Ok, I will give this a try, give me a little bit of time to see if it will work, since this happens randomly to begin with and the layout error may not show up again until tomorrow if this doesn't fix it. Thank you.

Comment: if it still happens, you can give me the link to web site and i will take a look on it. If you want.

Comment: Ok, Thanks for you help, I have updated the code and uploaded it to the server so I will give it a day or two, If it works I'll be sure to mark your answer as correct

Comment: I'm coming back to this question because just today, my menu layout loaded vertically again for the first time since the question. Here is a link to the website if you could take a look,  [link](http://pbradleyonline.com/Used_Equipment.aspx). The home page menu is loading correctly but the Used equipment one is not. They both use the same style sheet and master page.

Comment: You have wrong menu struct. you added inside <li> of main menu sub menu with <ul>, and this that makes the mess, if you do so you should use js/jq to hide sub menus and display them only on hover, or you can make all memu liks in main memu so they all will be in the same and one <ul>. No <ul> will be inside of <li> of main menu

Comment: Ok, thanks I will correct the menu structure and see what happens